# What is NETWORK_STATE_UNMETERED?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, wifi, gcm-network-manager

I need to use GcmNetworkManager to schedule a PeriodicTask. I need to tell the system to transfer only when there is WIFI. But the choices are NETWORK_STATE_CONNECTED, NETWORK_STATE_UNMETERED, and NETWORK_STATE_ANY. Does anyone know if **NETWORK_STATE_UNMETERED** is just a fancy way of saying **WIFI**? (please provide supporting reference. Thanks.)

Comment: NETWORK_STATE_UNMETERED is a connection where you are not paying per mb of usage.

Comment: But how does Android know whether or not the Wi-Fi connection is unmetered? For example, if my app is connecting via the Wi-Fi hotspot on a friend's mobile phone (who has limited data), then surely this Wi-Fi connection is metered - but Android will regard it as *unmetered*??

Answer (score 1):

Yes. According to the two books below, **NETWORK_STATE_UNMETERED** means that your app requires WIFI Network.

It is called "unmetered" in the sense that "time of use won't be measured so you won't be charged for that".

1. [Android High Performance Programming
   By Enrique Lopez Manas, Diego Grancini](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=aaXWDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA243&lpg=PA243&dq=NETWORK_STATE_UNMETERED&source=bl&ots=DLQGDPHwG4&sig=toZZjyIqIhToiHQIJzDk__aVyY0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiho6qO35PTAhUMiZAKHSZMAGcQ6AEISjAI#v=onepage&q=NETWORK_STATE_UNMETERED&f=false)
2. [Android: Programming for Developers
   By John Horton, Helder Vasconcelos, Raul Portales](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=nGzWDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA826&lpg=PA826&dq=NETWORK_STATE_UNMETERED&source=bl&ots=S6AB_WIAi3&sig=FI-fG_P_lSncrdVAMtQAz6RgbSg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiho6qO35PTAhUMiZAKHSZMAGcQ6AEITjAJ#v=onepage&q=NETWORK_STATE_UNMETERED&f=false)